# Combine two dataframes based on the values of a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following dataframe:

```
Code, Name_A
1,    Name1
2,    Name2
3,    Name3
4,    Name4
5,    Name5
6,    Name6
```

and another dataframe, called df2, which has a subset of the rows of dataframe 1:

```
Code, Name_B
1,    Name1
3,    Name3
6,    Name6
```

I would like to combine df1 and df2 to construct a new dataframe, df3, as follow:

```
Code, Name_A,Name_B
1,    Name1, Name1
2,    Name2,
3,    Name3, Name3
4,    Name4,
5,    Name5,
6,    Name6, Name6
```

Comment: Do you need a left join like `left_join(df1,df2,by="Code")`?

Comment: Here's a useful reference:  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html  (it's tidyverse style, if that matters to you).